# mod_rewrite add trailing slash and pass to index.php

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

When I request my website, I'm trying to add trailing slash to the URL and then pass it to index.php as parameter using mod_rewrite.

My *.htaccess* file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On    

#Add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [R]

#Pass to index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

And in my *index.php* file just outputs the parameter:

```
<?php echo $_GET["p"]; ?>
```

But when I type to the adress bar anything except *http://mydomain.com/*, for example *http://mydomain.com/contact*, the **php** always outputs `http://mydomain.com/index.php`. So `http://mydomain.com/index.php` was somehow passed as the parameter instead of the requested page such as `contact`, but I don't know why...

Also, when I edit

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ index.php?p=$1
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /index.php?p=$1
```

and I type URL e.g. `mydomain.com/contact` Apache gives me 302 Found and a link to where it was moved, but it links to the same page...

Any Ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apache has a nice long writeup for this specifically.

**Trailing Slash Problem**

Every webmaster can sing a song about the problem of the trailing slash on URLs referencing directories. If they are missing, the server dumps an error, because if you say /~quux/foo instead of /~quux/foo/ then the server searches for a file named foo. And because this file is a directory it complains. Actually it tries to fix it itself in most of the cases, but sometimes this mechanism need to be emulated by you. For instance after you have done a lot of complicated URL rewritings to CGI scripts etc.
Solution:

The solution to this subtle problem is to let the server add the trailing slash automatically. To do this correctly we have to use an external redirect, so the browser correctly requests subsequent images etc. If we only did a internal rewrite, this would only work for the directory page, but would go wrong when any images are included into this page with relative URLs, because the browser would request an in-lined object. For instance, a request for image.gif in /~quux/foo/index.html would become /~quux/image.gif without the external redirect!

```
So, to do this trick we write:

RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /~quux/
RewriteRule    ^foo$  foo/  [R]
```

The crazy and lazy can even do the following in the top-level .htaccess file of their homedir. But notice that this creates some processing overhead.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteBase    /~quux/
RewriteCond    %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  -d
RewriteRule    ^(.+[^/])$           $1/  [R]
```

It can be found here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Comment: "If [the trailing slash is] missing, the server dumps an error" You must be talking about Windows servers, because under Linux both cases are the same: `cd /home` == `cd /home/` (same is valid for URL's)

Comment: I have the automatic shash adding turned off with `DirectorySlash Off` directive, but the rewriting still isn't working...